# Windows key + L locks my PC, but doesn't let me type in password again (in a proper way)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8.1, razer-keyboard

Whenever I want to lock the PC, I press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. If I hold the Windows key down for too long, it starts wanting to type l. And it does not stop typing l even if I hit the L key myself.

This is not the only thing wrong, if I am to log in again -- after successfully locking my computer -- I can't do anything on my computer, literally. I can't type or nothing, and it seems to be the Windows key that is "stuck" in some odd way.

#### System Info:

- **Keyboard:** Razer BlackWidow Ultimate 2013
- **OS:** Windows 8.1 Pro

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to test with another keyboard? It sounds a bit more like a hardware issue.

Comment: @Dracs I did try with another keyboard, and it didn't do anything strange. What do you suppose I do now?

Comment: I Also tried out another USB-port, and what do you know, it works perfectly. Only downside is that the "working" USB-ports are on the front of my computer.

Comment: Also, if I lock the computer from a start menu (I installed a 3rd party one, since this is Windows 8.1), the same problem occurs when I have logged in.
It appears as if the enter-keys are stuck, but they don't "un-stuck" when I press them.